# iOS app user interface not updated on device

Tags: iphone, ios5, user-interface

I have a strange issue when I run my application on device: everything is up to date except the user interface which is the old one. In the simulator I have this result:

[image: Simulator]

But on the device I have this:

[image: Device]

I tried uninstall and reinstall and even uninstall, shut down and reinstall the app but nothing changed..

Comment: Which iOS version is the device running vs. the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Shift-Command-K to make a clean build.
2. Shift-Option-Command-K to clean the build folder.
3. Quit Xcode. Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/(your project name). Sometimes old .xib files hang around here.
4. Open the iOS Simulator and go to iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings.

This lovely feature gave me an hour of trouble this afternoon -- hopefully you'll have an easier time.

Comment: Do not blame me but.. the newer (and right) UI is the one in the simulator, not in the device.. Is it the same?

Comment: That makes me slightly less certain about my answer, but I'd still give it a shot. At the very least, it can't hurt anything.